# Make my function set variables in the current scope

Tags: php, variables

Can it be done?

```
function my_function(&$array){

  // processing $array here

  extract($array); // create variables but not here
}

function B(){

  $some_array = array('var1' => 23423, 'var2' => 'foo');

  my_function($some_array);

  // here I want to have $var, $var2 (what extract produced in my function)
}
```

For example parse_str() is able to do this.

Comment: You can't swap `my_function()` with `extract()`?

Comment: @alex: I'm assuming `my_function` does some processing on the `extract`ed variables,

Comment: I can run extract after my_function, but I was wondering if I can do this within my function

Comment: @Alex: I suggest doing `extract` after `my_function`, that just sounds like easiest solution.

Comment: I guess the best way would be using `list()` in conjunction with `extract`

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: How would you use `list` *with* `extract`?  Don't they do pretty much the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** Wasn't thinking in my first answer.

The answer is no; you can move the `extract` call inside your function `B`, that's about it.

Btw, with some more background of your problem I could improve my answer :)

Comment: Or, ya know, use `extract`, which kinda does this. :-P

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it doesn't extract into the context it was called, just the global...

```
function my_function($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
      global $$key;
      $$key = $value;
  }
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/uatB94tU).

However, I wouldn't recommend it. It's rarely (but not exclusively never) a good idea to unpack a bunch of stuff into the global scope.

As far as extracting into the scope the function was called, I don't think it's possible, or at least, worth doing.

Comment: How about `$GLOBALS[$key] = $value;`?

Comment: `$GLOBALS` contains all global variables.  Doing `$GLOBALS['test'] = 12;` means `$test` is now `12`.  Though you may need `global $test;` first.

Comment: ok so then the correct answer should be "no" :) it appears that php hides things from us

Comment: Won't work, the other function still needs to have `global $var1, $var2;` for that to work.

Comment: @Rocket 'tis been a while since I've used PHP. Thanks for re-educating me :)

Comment: @Jack That is mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to return a value if you want to make a one-liner.

```
function my_function($array){

  // processing $array here

  // Return the processed array
  return $array;
}

function B(){

  $some_array = array('var1' => 23423, 'var2' => 'foo');

  // If you don't pass by reference, this works
  extract(my_function($some_array));
}
```

PHP doesn't allow you to play with the scope of another function, and that is a good thing. If you were in an instanciated object, you could use `$this->` to work on a property, but I guess you already know this.

Comment: You'd have to make `my_function` return `$array` for this to work.  In this case it's editing the array via reference, so you'd need to do: `my_function($some_array); extract($some_array);`